# "Development of technology" vs. "technology development"

Tags: emphasis, modifier-vs-of

I was wondering which form is the correct one, "technology development" or "the development of technology".

For example:

> 1. The pace of technology development affected me in several ways.
> 2. The pace of development of technology affected me in several ways.

In the second example I *try* to emphasize the speed of development more.

Comment: If you find any mistakes in the question, or this comment please do correct me, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First is ungrammatical, the second is just about grammatical, but in my view too wordy!

You need the adjectival form of technology, namely 'technological'.  'The pace of technological development'.

Comment: If neither of the two is correct, you're saying that the second sentence should be "The pace of development of technological affected me in several ways."

Comment: @Lester Nubla. No I am not saying that. I will acknowledge that 'the pace of development of technology' scrapes through as being grammatical, (and i have amended my answer) but is not an erudite way of speaking English (You have the preposition 'of' twice, separated by a single word. That, in my view, sounds clumsy.). 'Technological development' is snappier and more usual, I believe.

Comment: That's better! Now I've upvoted it.